# Mongoose query error does not return data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Hi friends i have this schema in my db

```
const impresionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 id:{type:Number, required: true},
 ap:{type:String, required: true},
 mac_address:{type:String, required: true},
 campaniaId:{type:String, required: true}
}, {versionKey: false});
```

and this is my query to db

```
router.get("/:start/:end", (req, res, next) => {

const start = parseInt(req.params.start);
const end = parseInt(req.params.end);
const unique = req.query.unique !== undefined;

Impresion.find({id:{$gte:start, $lte:end}}).then(impresiones => {
 res.status(200).json({
  message: "Impresiones fetched successfully!",
  impresiones: impresiones
  });
 });
});
```

Mongo does not return any data, but there are multiple documents according to the query

**sorry for my english

Comment: Show a document you expect to match and add `mongoose.set("debug", true)` to your application code and include the actual query issued to MongoDB that will log as a result of that "debug" setting. Also note the mongoose version in use, since earlier versions typically transpose `id` and `_id`. Newever versions "appear" to leave this alone.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

`Impressions.find({id:{$gte:start, $lte:end}}).toArray().then(arr => {}).catch()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed exporting the schema so export schema like: -

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection(your hostname, you database name');

 const impresionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 id:{type:Number, required: true},
 ap:{type:String, required: true},
 mac_address:{type:String, required: true},
 campaniaId:{type:String, required: true}
}, {versionKey: false});

var Impresion = db.model('Impresion', impresionSchema);
module.exports = Impresion;  // this is what you want
```

Comment: Thanks for your help friend, the db connection its good. If I remove the filter it returns the data,